# Merging features by admin or sovereingt

Tags: gdal, geojson, ogr2ogr, topojson

I followed Mike Bostock's '[Let's Make a Map](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/map/)' tutorial to make a GeoJSON map of the EU starting from a 1:10M cultural admin0 shapefile from Natural Earth. The problem that I'm facing if that some of the countries are split into multiple features, i.e.:

`{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "SOVEREIGNT": "Italy", "ADMIN": "Italy", "ADM0_A3": "ITA", "SUBUNIT": "Sardinia" },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "SOVEREIGNT": "Italy", "ADMIN": "Italy", "ADM0_A3": "ITA", "SUBUNIT": "Isole Pelagie" },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "SOVEREIGNT": "Italy", "ADMIN": "Italy", "ADM0_A3": "ITA", "SUBUNIT": "Pantelleria" },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "SOVEREIGNT": "Italy", "ADMIN": "Italy", "ADM0_A3": "ITA", "SUBUNIT": "Italy" },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "SOVEREIGNT": "Italy", "ADMIN": "Italy", "ADM0_A3": "ITA", "SUBUNIT": "Sicily" }`

N.B. I stripped most properties from the above the example.

The command I used to generate the GeoJSON looked something like:

`ogr2ogr   -f GeoJSON   -where "ADM0_A3 IN ('PRT', 'ESP', 'ITA', ...)"   myMap.json   ne_10m_admin_0_map_subunits.shp`

My question is:

Is there a way that I can have all the feature geometries that have a common ADMIN/SOVEREIGNT merged so that the GeoJSON output will only contain a single entry per country?